# How to fill gridview when we specify the columns in designer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am really newbie in this but can someone tell me how can i add values in GridView, when i define columns in designer. I have one column of type `Buttonfield`. My default.asax code is given below.

**Code**:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTableHolding" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" Width="1184px" 
    BorderStyle="None" CssClass="DDGridView" 
        onrowcommand="gvTableHolding_RowCommand" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
        EmptyDataText=" No Data!" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Holding Register " />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Set Value" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" ShowHeader="True" Text="ChangeValue" 
                CommandName="ChangeValue" HeaderText="Buttons" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Default Value" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Decimal" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hex" />
        </Columns>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" 
        HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you want to show in `Button` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know why you want to show the column header in button filed. You can use the `TemplateField` & `ItemField` inside the `Column` tag, foe e.g:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderText="Holding Register " Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Holding_Register")%>' ID="lblUserId"
                            runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderText="Description" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>' ID="lblUserId"
                            runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `DataField` in each column first. Like this -

```
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Holding Register " DataField="Holding_Register"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description"/>
</Columns>
```

Then bound the data source with the grid from code.

```
gvTableHolding.DataSource = GetData();
gvTableHolding.DataBind();
```

One thing you should remember, in `GetData()` whatever you return (DataTable or List), those property names should match with the `DataField` you defined in Grid.

Comment: Thanks, really works! But now i saw the columns two times in browser. The GetData() return DataTable with the same columns like this defined in GridView.